# Calling Array.includes() on a accumulator raises a TypeError; .reduce()

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to reduce an Array that contains any duplicate words. Upon trying to return the result I get the follow error `TypeError: acc.includes is not a function`. The way I'm interpreting the error is that the method is not available for the array `acc` due to the version of JavaScript being used.

Am I correct in assuming this or is there something else going on here?

```
function removeDuplicateWords (s) {
  return s.split(" ").reduce(function(acc, value, index, array) {
    if (array.indexOf(value) === array.lastIndexOf(value)) {
      return acc.push(value);
    } else {
        return !acc.includes(value) ? acc.push(value) : "";
    }
  }, [])
}
```

Comment: This can't work: `return acc.push(value);` returns an integer, but the callback must return the accumulator array. Can you show a [mcve] with real input and expected output? Beyond this, it seems like you could dump the array into a Set to remove duplicates easier: `[...new Set(s.split(" "))]`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning array in your function. Whatever you return from the callback of `reduce()` it will become `acc` for next iteration. You need to return the array.

`push()` method is inplace(it will modify original array) method which returns the `length` of new array not the new array with new value.

```js
function removeDuplicateWords (s) {
  return s.split(" ").reduce(function(acc, value, index, array) {
    if (array.indexOf(value) === array.lastIndexOf(value)) {
      return [...acc, value]
    } else {
        return !acc.includes(value) ? [...acc, value] : acc;
    }
  }, [])
}


console.log(removeDuplicateWords("hello hello hey"))
```

The same thing could be achieved using `Set()` and spread operator.

```js
const removeDups = str => [... new Set(str.split(' '))];

console.log(removeDups('hello hey hello'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` instead like shown below. `filter` has three parameters `item`, `index` & `array`. And `indexOf` will return index of first occurrence of value. So it will always return first value only thus duplicate value will be removed.

```js
function removeDuplicateWords(s) {
  return s.split(" ").filter((x, i, a) => a.indexOf(x) === i);
}

console.log(removeDuplicateWords("hello hello hey"));
```